# Insert predefined message into existing conversation (Android)

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

Is there any way that I can insert a predefined message into an existing conversation in the inbox from an app built on the Android platform?

With this code I am able to retrieve the last sent and received messages.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);

Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMS, null, null, null, null);
cur.moveToNext();

String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));   
String add = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
String time = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("date"));
String protocol = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("protocol"));       

String contactName = "";
Uri personUri = Uri.withAppendedPath( ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(add));  
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(personUri, new String[] { PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null );  
if( c.moveToFirst() ) {  
             int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);  
             contactName = c.getString(nameIndex);
}
c.close();
cur.close();

String out = "";
Date d = new Date(Long.valueOf(time)); 

if (protocol == null)
    out = "Sending to: "+ contactName + " <"+add +">\nDate: "+d +"\nBody: "+body+"\n\n";
else 
    out = "Received from: "+ contactName + " <"+add +">\nDate: "+d +"\nBody: "+body+"\n\n";

tv.setText(out);
setContentView(tv);

}
```

Is there any way that I can incorporate this into my broadcast receiver (SmsReceiver.java)? Hopefully there is a way that I can trigger an event so that when a new message is received I can insert a predefined message into the conversation related to the newest text message in the inbox.

While I'm at it. Is there any way to accurately retrive the native phone number without asking the user to enter it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using the following code in my receiver.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put("address", "0123456789");
 values.put("body", "Message goes here");
  context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), values);
```